# Extending SharePoint search with an OPAC Search (library system)

Tags: sharepoint, search

I'm wondering if someone has some experience in extending the SharePoint Search so that users are able to search the Online Public Access Catalogue (OPAC) of a library system.

Would this be possible at all? What are your experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OPAC system supports OpenSearch you could use Federated Search to add a search location in the Shared Service Provider.